# Tabbar for views without tabbar items iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to use the tab bar controller in order to have a home view load with the tabbar items at the bottom but does not create a tab bar item for the home view. I managed to create views, display the tab bar on these views and create a respective tabbar item but I do not know how to NOT create the tabbar item.

thanks - hope this makes sense

Comment: I don't get your question. What do you mean by saying: "I managed to create views, display the tab bar on these views and create a respective tabbar item but I do not know how to NOT create the tabbar item."

Comment: lets say i have three views - home, first and second. I want home to appear onscreen and i want first and second tabs to appear in the tabbar - BUT I Dont want a home tab bar item to appear anywhere. is that possible?

Comment: no it doesn't make sense... but i'm still going to try telling you something... if what you want, is to add a tab bar to a UIView, instead of the main UIWindow (as in the default tab bar project), UIWindow is a subclass of UIView, i.e. just another view... so you can add it to any view you want exactly as it is added to the window..

Comment: its not letting me add the tab bar to the window

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to hide the tabbar or distinct items you add to the tabbar controller?

Hiding the tabbar:
tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;

Else:
If you don't want to see an item in the tabbar, don't add it. Manage further views within the controller you load into the tabbar controller by e.g. using an UINavigationController

Comment: but if I dont add a view controller to the tab view controller, I don't see the tab bar

Comment: not adding a controller to a tab view controller is not making any sense, in this case you don't need one. and of course, if you don't add a controller it is empty and you don't see any tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tabbar automatically like this code sample:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
   tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

   MyViewController* vc1 = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
   MyOtherViewController* vc2 = [[MyOtherViewController alloc] init];

   NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil];
   tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;

   // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
   [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}
```

[More about UITabBarControllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW15)